# Vb.NET Read Excel Missing Data

Tags: vb.net, excel

```
Private Sub readexcel()
    Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & txtFileName.Text & "; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")

    Dim oconn As New OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", cnn)
    cnn.Open()
    Dim adp As New OleDbDataAdapter(oconn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim ds As DataSet
    adp.Fill (dt)

    dgvExcelData.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    dgvExcelData.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically
    dgvExcelData.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

The above code reads Excel into Grid View,but some data will missing. Could someone tell me why?

[image]

Comment: Try it with `IMEX=1` in your connection string. `IMEX=1;` tells the driver to always read "intermixed" (numbers, dates, strings etc) data columns as text. See [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel)

Comment: @SiddharthRout `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & txtFileName.Text & "; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;` correct?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Error `Could not find installable ISAM.`

Comment: @SiddharthRout is Excel u know? not Access

Comment: @SiddharthRout same,data still missing, i uploaded my .xlsx https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/a.xlsx?w=AABg6LG2-YwkvZ3VeEtqX3V2Gr-XPi8GxV-iEQgxZsiN5w

Comment: It's asking me to sign in. Can you upload it in www.wikisend.com and then share the link here?

Comment: @SiddharthRout http://wikisend.com/download/296426/a.xlsx

Comment: @SiddharthRout Excel File Row No 36253,please concert on this row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, ACE reads the first 8 rows of data and use that to decide the data type of each column.

If the data in those 8 rows in a column is of the same type then that type is assumed else it will assume text by default. After 8 columns it doesn't check it.

If your columns have mixed data types then you will have to make a small change in the registry.

Go to

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel`

and change the value of the key `TypeGuessRows` from `8` to `0`

[image]

Now test the below code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strCon As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & txtFileName.Text &
                           "; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"""

    Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection(strCon)

    Dim oconn As New OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", cnn)
    cnn.Open()

    Dim adp As New OleDbDataAdapter(oconn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    adp.Fill(dt)

    dgvExcelData.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    dgvExcelData.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically
    dgvExcelData.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

And this is the output

[image]

Comment: how come the NO K/P LAMA are auto rounded...example 8051815355155 will become 8051815355160

Comment: Sorry? I am not sure what are you asking?

Comment: change the NO KP LAMA to Number Format, then the number will auto rounded...why?(i have saved the dataset data to excel file)